# Accessing Vertica Database through Oozie sqoop

Tags: sqoop, oozie, vertica

I have written an Oozie workflow to access an HP Vertica database through Sqoop. This is on a Cloudera VM. I am getting the following error in Yarn logs after running:

```
     RROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop:    java.lang.RuntimeException:        Could not load db driver class: dbDriver
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: dbDriver
     at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:848)
     at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
     at org.apache.sqoop.tool.EvalSqlTool.run(EvalSqlTool.java:64)
     at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
     at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
     at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
     at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)"

This is a snippet from the jobprops file:
      "dbDriver=com.vertica.jdbc.Driver
     dbHost=host***.assist.*** 
     dbName=vertica247
     dbPassword=*****
     dbPort=5433
     dbSchema=simod_chat
     dbStagingSchema=simodstg_chat
     dbUser=vertica"
```

What should I specify for --connection-manager? When I run the same workflow outside the VM, it runs without the connection-manager argument?

Comment: Is `123@abc` your real password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states:

```
Could not load db driver class: dbDriver
```

There are likely two problems:

1. The JDBC URL is probably incorrect
2. The JDBC Jar needs to be included in the workflow

For the JDBC URL, make sure it looks like this:

```
jdbc:vertica://VerticaHost:portNumber/databaseName
```

For the JDBC jar, it needs to be included with the workflow. Check out [this article](http://ingest.tips/2015/02/12/sqoop-hbase-oozie/) for a brief example on how to do this with HBase. TLDR: When you run Sqoop through oozie, you have to include the driver in the workflow:

```
<workflow-app name="sqoop-import" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
  <start to="sqoop-import"/>
  <action name="sqoop-import">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
      <command>import --connect jdbc:vertica://VerticaHost:portNumber/databaseName --username test --password test --table test</command>
      <file>/user/admin/vertica-jdbc.jar#vertica-jdbc.jar</file>
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
  </action>
  <kill name="kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
  </kill>
  <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Note the line:

```
<file>/user/admin/vertica-jdbc.jar#vertica-jdbc.jar</file>
```

It will automatically be included in your sqoop job.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. As per the post, I have added my jdbc jar to the HDFS location /user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop. However, despite the URL and the files being added, I am still getting the error. Do I need to add a --connection-manager argument?

Comment: No, sqoop should automatically choose the right connection manager from the jdbc URL. You might need to add ``--driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver``.

Comment: Hi, yeah. I have added that. Somehow it is not being picked up.

Comment: I'd ask your question on the Sqoop mailing list then: user@sqoop.apache.org.